# Elastic Beanstalk can`t pull docker image from DockerHub

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-elastic-beanstalk, dockerhub, dockerrun.aws.json

I wanted to make a CI/CD with Java application (random application on github).
I followed this tutorial: https://www.blog.labouardy.com/elastic-beanstalk-docker-tips/ (but I use GitHub Actions). 
Everything works except for the pull image in Elastic Beanstalks.
I made a separate push of the **Dockerrun.aws.json** file, but the download failed.

I tried to take any other image from the DockerHub (for example oobsri/tomcat8) and put it in **Dockerrun.aws.json** file. And it booted successfully...!

Problem: When I want to update a version of app via docker image, Elastic Beanstalk shows an error while downloading the docker image from DockerHub.

Example of erorrs from ElasticBeanstalk: 
"Instance deployment failed. For details, see 'eb-engine.log'."
"Instance deployment failed to download the Docker image. The deployment failed."
"[Instance: i-0dafdbbfc40f0edd2] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: Engine execution has encountered an error.."

**My simple project in GitHub:** https://github.com/DANIILNEDOSTUP/my-project
Main script in **.github/workflows/ci.yml**
**My docker image on DockerHub:** https://hub.docker.com/repository/docker/daniilnedostup/java-app

Comment: Can you also paste the `eb-engine.log` content?

Comment: Of course.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1cIm9ahjdJE-_CCurwPNNsqze2T2NGsiV/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

ANSWER:
The Elastic Beanstalk defaults to reading the "**latest**" tag when pulling from DockerHub. I didn`t have it. When I added everything worked successfully :)